# Can't boot into Ubuntu 16.04 dueto rebuilding mbr

Tags: boot

I have rebuild mbr using AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition.
Now I can not boot into ubuntu although ubuntu partitions are present properly/

Comment: That looks like its is mostly if not all Windows repair tools. Have you tried Boot-Repair? Is system UEFI or bIOS? What brand/model system? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: laptop : hp (Notebook-15 ay516tx) UEFI but i installed ubuntu in legacy mode.
and  currently I cant boot into Ubuntu anyhow.Not also from pressing boot key of my laptop.

Comment: Can you still boot live installer with HP boot keys.

Comment: I can boot into windows using boot key but not to ubuntu
Its showing that no boot media found.

Comment: Since HP that is typical. HP violated UEFI standard and includes description as part of UEFI boot. But if Ubuntu BIOS install, you may have to change UEFI settings to boot in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode. If Ubuntu UEFI install, you have to do one of the work arounds, usually if dual booting, using the fallback or hard drive boot entry. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info